# Default values for custom cocoa object

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nstextfield

There are a few parameters that I always set when creating `MyLabel` and rather than having to write them out everytime I would rather just set them as default for the custom class.

I have tried this with no luck:

```
@interface MyLabel: NSTextField
@end

@implementation MyLabel
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setWantsLayer:YES];
        [self setSelectable:YES];
        [self setEditable:NO];
        [self setBordered:NO];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

init is just not called.

`MyLabel` is called like:

```
MyLabel* error_label = [[MyLabel alloc] initWithFrame: ...
```

Comment: How did you call this? If you are using this through nib files then put this code in awakeFromNib.

Comment: See edit in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `initWithFrame`. Call only with `init`.

Try below code

```
MyLabel* error_label = [[MyLabel alloc] init];
```

You can set frame after initialization like below

```
[error_label setFrame::CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0)]; // set co-ordinates accordingly
```